# Starting cmd in directory Windows Explorer is currently

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

Is there a way to start cmd (using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or even more preferably [Hotkeyz](http://www.skynergy.com/hotkeyz.html)) in the directory in which Explorer is currently (i.e. in the directory which is currently open in Windows Explorer)?

While waiting in here, I also stumbled onto a script which supposedly should do that, but it doesn't work. Can anyone see the possible problem which may stop her from doing the above mentioned.

Full script below, c/pasted from [here](http://tictechtoc.shashikant.in/2010/01/autohotkey-open-new-command-prompt-from.html)

```
; Opens a command prompt with the current folder 
; when you press Ctrl+Alt+H in Explorer
; or the command prompt

^!h::
if WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") 
or WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass")
{
 ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
 Send !d
 Sleep 10
 Send ^c
 Run, cmd /K "cd /D `"%clipboard%`""
 Clipboard := ClipSaved
 ClipSaved =
 return
}
else if WinActive("ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass") 
{
 Send ^c 
 Sleep 10
 Send explorer .{Enter}
 Sleep 10
 return
}
exit
```

Comment: Retag done... =)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I install Windows XP, one of the first pieces of software I install is the **Open command window here** Powertoy from Microsoft.  It's available free from the [Powertoys page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx).  Right-click on a folder in Explorer and you get a new option to open a command window in that folder.

Comment: Yes, I know of that one. I'm actualy using one even better (imho), that I found somewhere on the net, that opens the cmd in the currently open directory, but I would still prefer a keyboard option with a shortcut. Also, it will be a part of some bigger script (if I manage to complete it <- hopefully).

Comment: @Rook would you mind sharing this "better one"? It might benefit others also.

Comment: @BloodPhilia - Of course I wouldn't, perish the thought. Aa a matter of fact, I was just now looking for the download link. And I shouldn't have used the word better, but maybe different. It does practically the same thing with a different (to me more natural) approach. http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/

Answer (score 0):

I like [Command Prompt Explorer Bar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/commandbar.aspx).  It extends Explorer with the functionality of a command prompt.  Opens in the folder you are currently pointing to, using Ctrl+M.